# Fedora: Launch graphical installation of package

Tags: fedora, yum

I am creating a graphical application that in the first run checks if all needed software is installed (please, don't answer about deb/rpm dependencies). The own application (in Python) detects if the app is running in Ubuntu or Fedora. If in Ubuntu, I launch this command to install the required packages:

```
apturl apt://xdotool
```

This launchs a dialog asking the user if he wants to install it, and then asks for password:

[image: Dialogue Box-Image]

Is there a similar command in Fedora (of course, in a base desktop installation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [PackageKit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/pk-faq.html#session-methods) to do this. From that site, here is a slightly-modified version of the example code for python:

```
import dbus

try:
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
except dbus.DBusException, e:
    print 'Unable to connect to dbus: %s' % str(e)
    sys.exit()
try:
    proxy = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.PackageKit', '/org/freedesktop/PackageKit')
    iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit.Modify')
    iface.InstallPackageNames(dbus.UInt32(0), ["xdotool","otherpackage","whatever"], "show-confirm-search,hide-finished")
except dbus.DBusException, e:
    print 'Unable to use PackageKit: %s' % str(e)
```

Bonus! This should work on GNOME on *both* Fedora and Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! I have made a quick test in Ubuntu and Fedora and it seems to work fine. The only problem is that in Fedora (Ubuntu Shell), the dialog doesn't appear to user, just a notification that he has to click. Do you know if there is any option to present the dialog directly to the user, without a notification? (this doesn't happen in Ubuntu, where the dialog is shown to the user without any additional interaction)

Comment: Not sure; I think it just might be the new way of doing things. You might ask on the PackageKit mailing list.